# Is there a fundamental ontology in Physics? What is the universe fundamentally "made of" according to Physics?

Tags: ontology, philosophy-of-physics, physics

Is there a fundamental ontology in Physics? According to Physics, what are the fundamental "things" (whatever they may be) that in combination define the whole universe, such that they are not themselves defined in terms of other simpler "things"?

Comment: String theory,  preon theory (dismissed one). Also, quarks already may be smallest blocks.

Comment: Isn't this a question for https://physics.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: @rus9384 I don't think it's acceptable to leave it at "quarks may be the smallest blocks". That's a subset of our presently experimentally-verified truth. There are several non-quark things we believe are fundamental, the most well-known of which are photons and electrons.

Comment: @Chair, yes, of course, there are leptons and photons (and, probably, some other particles I forgot or never knew).

Comment: @Schiphol, no, it isn't, because of [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/408585/is-there-a-fundamental-ontology-in-physics-what-are-the-fundamental-building-b)

Comment: Information https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_physics#Wheeler's_"it_from_bit"

Comment: @CriglCragl, it's unclear whether universe is discrete or continuous. In second case I think it's not the case.

Comment: @rus9384 On the contrary. That is like saying we don't know if light is a particle or a wave, misleading. It has a probability field, continuous, of probability to interact, in a particle way. Where information as fundamental gets super useful, is in terms of understanding the role of time, so with the candidates for quantum gravity, as yet not fully developed.

Comment: Ontology is the business of metaphysics. Physics does not concern itself with fundamental theories and is concerned with ontology only up to a point. It can never have a fundamental theory or complete ontology. This is a task for metaphysics.

Comment: According to which physics ? There are so many contrary theories now it's hard to actually tell which one is better.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, we consider [these seven units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SI_base_unit), and hence the quantities they represent, to be fundamental: they perfectly satisfy the condition "not defined in terms of other simpler existing things". All other physical quantities can be defined in terms of these units, as far as we know, but there are propositions that the list needs expansion. You can think of these as the building blocks for **perception and measurement**. They don't just describe composition, but also include phenomenon, which is good because physics discusses both what things fundamentally *are*, and how they *behave*.

From a different perspective, I could answer with reference to the [Standard model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model). It features 17 fundamental particles (plus antiparticles for several of them) which **make up everything** and are organized into very different groups based on their properties like mass and superimposability in spacetime. Briefly, they're 6 quarks, which are (simplification alert) heavy and interact with a particular force (strong nuclear force), leptons (small rest mass, no strong interaction), gauge bosons (force-mediators, sometimes massless), and the Higgs boson.Theories describing a more fundamental composition of the universe exist (most importantly string theory), but are not proven and currently theoretically unprovable, so I'll ignore their existence.

Comment: Regarding ontology, it may be interesting to note that you can both interpret the more essentialist units/fundamental particles and the *interactions* they represent as being the metaphysical foundation, the latter further being interpretable as either *relation* or *process*, depending on the interpretation of this widely pragmatist understanding of metaphysics. My limited understanding is that the philosophy of science (serious, not popular) is tending towards process ontologies as of now, as they circumvent dualisms and reductionisms inherent in any position close to essentialism.

Comment: I disagree that SI is ontologically fundamental. I'd say electric charge is more fundamental than electric current. And energy is thought to be more fundamental than mass.

Comment: @rus9384 they're **fundamental units, not quantities.** It's debatable, but I think there's a slight difference. My thoughts: these units were chosen not because they're more 'fundamental' in any way, but because they provide the most concise starting point for quantification of everything we know, including energy. Physically, we can argue that some of these units are actually manifestations of others, as you proved with the example of mass and energy, but that's not the point of calling those 7 units the fundamental units.

Comment: @Chair Who is the "we" that considers this all to be so? Your royal physics collapses entirely through depending on division by zero. The universe has no such problem. Ergo......

Comment: @HermanHofman "We" is the physics community (hopefully). And yes, many algebraic approaches to physics fail with division by zero, but calculus-based physics is (as far as I understand) relatively fool proof. But usually, when you try using zeros in equations, you're making a logical contradiction before a mathematical failure.

Comment: A fundamental theory cannot start with a myriad of phenomena and space-time. It is presicely these things that need to be reduced for such a theory.

Comment: @PeterJ I think that's the essence of the first part of my answer: we have so many phenomena to explain, but we've _reduced_ them to be expressible as combinations of those 7 units. That's one way of thinking of ontology.

The second approach (second paragraph) describes an alternative where you discuss the composition of everything in terms of mass and derived units from the first section.

Comment: Okay. But this is not a fundamental theory. Physics does not concern itself with what is prior to what it can observe so doesn't begin at the beginning. The is why ontology is metaphysics.

Comment: @PeterJ I didn't quite understand what you said, but here're my thoughts: the question asks for a summary of ontology from the point of view of physics. It asks about what physics considers to be the fundamental composition. Metaphysics approaches ontology differently, possibly in a truer sense of the term ontology, but that isn't what the question explicitly asks for.

Comment: @Chair - The word 'fundamental' seems unambiguous. Physics ends with the reduction of observable phenomena but this does not mean that these phenomena are fundamental. It just means that physics is not fundamental. I do not see this point as at all controversial. If physics could be fundamental there would be no need for metaphysics.

Comment: @PeterJ I wasn't sure what you referred to by 'this'... But in the end, we can agree that physics isn't the study of the most fundamental being But as far as physics is concerned, there are some things which are called fundamental, weather or not they're actually fundamental.

Comment: Yep. Physicists and metaphysicians often use the word in different ways. I feel 'fundamental' should always mean 'fundamental' to avoid giving the impression that physics deals with fundamentals and causing confusion on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you're thinking of building blocks in terms of something that is located in space and time, and if, when mentioning physics, you're thinking of quantum mechanics, this is an open philosophical question.

There are well defined fundamental *types* of "particles" in physics (quarks, leptons...) but instances of these types are not really represented as normal particles in a 3D space. They are represented as wave-functions, which are, mathematically speaking, fields in a 3N dimensional space (where N is the number of particles). This is necessary to account for quantum phenomena such as entanglement. But this kind of representation is rather abstract and looks nothing like building blocks of matter in space.

One can go on with this and assume that the purpose of physics is not to represent building blocks in a traditional sense (but perhaps only to predict phenomena or measurements) but some philosophers are dissatisfied and think that we should be able to interpret wave-functions in terms of a distribution of matter in space and time. This has led to a research program known as "primitive ontology". It consists in *completing* the bare theory with an interpretative layer: pointing at mathematical structures *derived* from the standard formalism and claiming "this is what really, really exists". Proposals include particle ontology (continuous in time but discrete in space, such as in Bohmian mechanics), matter densities (continuous in space and time) and events aka "flashes" (discrete in both space and time).

An alternative to this program developed by Albert consists in claiming that space is not 3 dimensional but 3N dimensional, so as to read off the ontology straight from the formalism. Our "normal" space would be emergent.

Note that these programs are not pursued by physicists, who tend to have a more pragmatic approach towards physics I would say, but by philosophers seeking a realist picture of the world based on physics. They all have difficulties, only metaphysical arguments favour one or the other (with no consensus), and in any case, contemporary physics is nothing like a straightforward representation of building blocks in space and time like classical physics was: it's a matter of interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

The elements of the universe are substances. Substances are inextricable composites of

1. primary matter (*materia prima*): "that which is in potency to substantial existence"<sup>1</sup>

and

2. substantial form (*forma substantialis*): "that which causes substantial existence in act"<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sup>1. St. Thomas Aquinas, [*On the Principles of Nature*](https://isidore.co/aquinas/DePrincNaturae.htm) §3
2. *idem* §5</sup>